# Get files added by a user in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial, how to get list of all files added by a particular user? Would greatly appreciate if this can be generated for a specific branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List all the files *added* (not modified) by user `eve` on any branch:

```
hg log --rev 'user(eve) and adds("glob:**")' --template '{file_adds}\n'
```

List all the files *added* (not modified) by user `eve` on branch `pizza`:

```
hg log --rev 'user(eve) and adds("glob:**") and branch(pizza)' --template '{file_adds}\n'
```

To learn more, see `hg help revsets` and `hg help templating`. Mercurial is a fantastic tool.